# Passing Nilable to a Sheet always considers is as null the first time

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a nilable variable, `targetLast5Day`, and I'm passing it to a sheetView I'm displaying. I'm declaring the variable as nil in the top level, and then assigning a value to it after a button's click. The problem is the first time I open the Sheet, it somehow considers the variable as nil, however, after the second time, it's the normal passed value, what's the issue?

```
@State private var targetLast5Day: Day? = nil // Mbt4t8l4 mnl mra: `Error`
```

That's the button setting value to the `targetLast5Day`

```
Button {
    targetLast5Day = day
    showLast5DaySheet.toggle()
} label: {
    CalendarItemMainPageView(passedDay: day)
}
```

That's the code for the sheet

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showLast5DaySheet) {
                        DaySheetView(passedDay: targetLast5Day != nil ? targetLast5Day! : svm.placeholderDayObj, habitMoved: { habit, to in
                            handleHabitMove(for: habit, to: to)
                        })
                    }
```

Comment: Why not use `.sheet(item:)` instead and pass `targetLast5Day`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)

Comment: This probably has to do with how you handle your state, which is missing from the question.